# home block area

Tags: dashboard

I have these 2 module in my home block area: left one is user module and 2nd is main menu block. I want to resize them to be same. I mean I want to make user menu bigger to equal main menu. where can I do this? this is picture:[image]

Answer (score 1):

You will have to modify the .css file in your site's theme. This can be one file or many files depending on the theme that you are using. [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/css/) has good tutorials on using css. You would also want to use [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) or [Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/elements) to inspect the block elements to find the blocks id or class so that you can set css rules for the height of the box.

To make your blocks the same height, your css rule might look something like:

```
#my-block-id-1,
#my-block-id-2 {
  height: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use fixed heights, things get complicated: http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/

THe easiest solution would be to use the property

```
 display: table-cell
```

Like this:

```
<div style="display:table;">
    <div style="display:table-cell">Block 1</div>
    <div style="display:table-cell">Block 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a background or something, i would create the background as a repeating image and then add it to the container div.

```
<div class="background-image-class">
  <div class="left-box"></div>
  <div class="right-box"></div>
</div>
```

And then clear your content out with clearfix or w/e so the image will span all the way down.